# Fast way to replace elements by zeros corresponding to zeros of another array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose we have two numpy arrays

```
a = np.array([ [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0], [-3, -1, 0] ])
b = np.array([ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ])
```

The goal is to set elements of b at the indices where a is 0. That is, we want to get an array

```
[ [1, 2, 0], [4, 0, 0], [7, 8, 0] ]
```

What is a fast way to achieve this?

I thought about generate a mask by $a$ first and then replace the values of b by this mask. But got lost on how to do this?

Comment: `b[a == 0] = 0`, assuming the arrays are conformable as in the example.

Comment: Thanks for the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is array assignment:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0], [-3, -1, 0]])
>>> b = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

>>> a==0  # This is a boolean mask, True where the elements of `a` are zero
array([[False, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True]])

>>> b[a==0] = 0  # So this is a masked assignment statement
>>> b
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [7, 8, 0]])
```

Documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`masked_array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) here:

```
np.ma.masked_array(b, a==0).filled(0)

array([[1, 2, 0],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [7, 8, 0]])
```

Helpful if you don't want to modify `b` in place.  You can replace `filled(0)` with whatever you'd like to set the elements equal to.